# 2 digit down-counter overwrites the low digit when the high digit changes?

Tags: assembly, 8051

my setup in multism is, 8051 microcontroller with two 7-segment display, of the 7-segment is connected to a 74ls373 latch with a push button connected to the port3.2 of 8051.

[image]

heres my code for a 99 countdown timer and loops infinitely after reaching 00, but still somehow whenever my tens decrement by one the ones also changes to that same number. how can i resolve this?

```
$MOD51  
start:
MOV R1,#9
MOV R2,#9
SETB P3.5
MOV A,R1
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
CLR P3.5
MOV A,R2
LCALL display
MOV P1,A
mov r1,#10
check_button:
jnb p3.2,button
dec r1
CJNE R1,#255, disp_ones
dec R2
CJNE R2,#255,disp_tens
lcall finish 
disp_tens:
SETB P3.5
MOV a,R2
LCALL display
MOV P1,a
lcall wait
CLR P3.5
MOV R1,#10
sjmp check_button
disp_ones:
CLR P3.5
MOV a,R1
LCALL display
MOV P1,a
lcall wait
sjmp check_button
button:
jnb p3.2,button_2
sjmp button
button_2:
sjmp check_button

wait:
MOV TMOD, #01H 
MOV TH0, #244 
MOV TL0, #0 
SETB TR0 
wait_loop:
JNB TF0, wait_loop 
CLR TR0 
CLR TF0 
RET
display:
INC A
MOVC A,@A+PC
RET
DB 0C0H ;0
DB 0F9H ;1
DB 0A4H ;2
DB 0B0H ;3
DB 99H ;4
DB 92H ;5
DB 82H ;6
DB 0F8H ;7
DB 80H ;8
DB 90H ;9
DB 88H ;A
DB 83H ;B
DB 0C6H ;C
DB 0A1H ;D
DB 86H ;E
DB 8EH ;F
finish:
sjmp finish
end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the formatting using the code button on the toolbar.

Comment: Since you have an extra `CLR P3.5` of course you change the ones as well. Remove that.